# how to declare int as array[] and past the value from main class?

Tags: java

How can I fix this problem? I want to change parameter and pvalue as array

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test5 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    int parameter[];
    int pvalue[];
    public Test5(int para[], int pv[]){
        parameter=para;
        pvalue=pv;

    }

    public void loopi(){

        int i = 0,j,k,l;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("enter parameter : ");
        parameter[i]= sc.nextInt();
         char group = 'a';
        for(i=1;i<=parameter[i];i++)
        {
            System.out.print("enter parameter value : ");
            pvalue[i]=sc.nextInt();


            for(j=1;j<=pvalue[i];j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" "+j+group+" \n");

            }
           seat++;
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        int i[] = null;
        int j[] = null;
        Test5 t=new Test5(i,j);
        t.loopi();
    }

}
```

Comment: you can initialize int i[] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91}; in your main method

Comment: There are lots of questions before giving any answer, What are you trying to do  ? What is seat++ ? why a single param have multiple values ? Is it correct ?

Comment: sorry i already change seat++ to group++..

Comment: `[I already changed] seat++ to group++` please do so in your post: edit. In the title, you probably mean _pass_, not `past`. Follow [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (Welcome to Stack Overflow!)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the arrays as command line arguments, then you need to convert all of the strings in args to int, you could try something like

```
int[] a = new int[args.length];
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
}
```